# Using ng-class with value from $scope

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

I have the following code:

```
<td ng-class="severityColor" ng-model="severity">text</td>
```

Css looks like:

```
.critical {
  color: red;
}
.warning {
  color: orange;
}
.info {
  color: black;
}
```

Severity is a variable inside $scope, and if I do something like:

```
<p>{{severity}}</p>
```

It prints either critical, warning or info accordingly. But this isn't changing the text color on the td tag. Am i missing something here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm completely retarded... Just as soon as I posted the question the answer became obvious... just changed the code to be:

```
<td ng-class="severity">text</td>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I should edit my answer to explain it bettter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it several ways. For example:

```
<td ng-class="{{severityColor}}" ng-model="severity">text</td>
```

or

```
<td class="{{severityColor}}" ng-model="severity">text</td>
```

or even with array notation:

```
<td ng-class="[severityColor]" ng-model="severity">text</td>
```

However, ... you original attempt should also work which means that you might have a naming typo (?): `severityColor` instead of `severity`.